# Rails3: how do I do ajax-y updating? like, changing the contents of a page without having to refresh the page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<li><%= link_to "Yes", { :controller => 'application', :action => 'start_game', :human_is_first => true  }, :remote => true  %></li>
```

in my controller:

```
  def start_game
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

in start_game.js.erb

```
$('.choose_options').fadeOut(1000);
```

my erb that calls start_game:

```
<div class="welcome">
  Hello!

  <div class="choose_turn">
    Would you like to go first?

    <ul class="choose_options">
      <li><%= link_to "Yes", { :controller => 'application', :action => 'start_game', :human_is_first => true  }, :remote => true  %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "No", { :controller => 'application', :action => 'start_game', :human_is_first => true  }, :remote => false  %></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when I click the link, the page redirects

```
Template is missing

Missing template application/start_game with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:builder, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :erb], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths "~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/tic-tac-toe-ai/tic-tac-toe-ai/app/views"
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

(I'm using jQuery 1.4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using respond_to, you might try using request.xhr? like so:

```
if request.xhr?
  render 'start_game.js.erb', :layout => false
end
```

Cody

Comment: Template is missing

Missing template application/start_game with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:builder, :rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :erb], :formats=>[:html]} in view paths "~/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/tic-tac-toe-ai/tic-tac-toe-ai/app/views"

Comment: Lol, can't believe I missed that. Cause you do the same sort of thing back in rails 2. =D

Comment: No problem, haha I missed it too!